# How to use SublimeLinter's cmd attribute

Tags: sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

I'm writing a SublimeLinter (a SublimeText plugin) plugin that uses `luacheck` for a custom syntax we use. So far I have it working with simply `cmd = 'luacheck @'`, the `@` being apparently replaced by the filename when SublimeLinter calls `luacheck`. The problem is that with SublimeLinter on 'background' mode, the warnings don't actually update until the file is saved, e.g. if I remove a line containing a warning the warning will still be there, just highlighting a blank space (until I save, that is). I have a feeling that this is because I'm using the `@` and since this is replaced by the filename, `luacheck` won't update till the file is updated. However, the SublimeLinter documentation on `cmd` is not great, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to write one correctly. None of the plugins on their GitHub seem to use `@`, either. If I copy the default `lua` plugin (which uses `cmd = 'luac -p * -'`) and use `cmd = 'luacheck * -'`, `luacheck` executes but only returns an I/O error. Could someone maybe provide some more insight into how SublimeLinter's `cmd` attribute works?

EDIT: I was able to fix this issue by using `tempfile_suffix = 'lua'` in `linter.py`. According to the SublimeLinter docs, this is used for linters that don't use `stdin`, so I suppose my issue could have been with `luacheck` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by using `tempfile_suffix = 'lua'` in `linter.py`. According to the SublimeLinter docs, this is used for linters that don't use stdin, so I suppose my issue could have been with luacheck instead.